# EF loading related entities with SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an sql statement that I'd like to return a list of Persons that have a related Department entity. The Person class has a Department ID and with the magic of entity framework it associates the correct Department object when I load it from the database.

My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON PERSON.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENT.ID
WHERE UPPER(FORENAME) LIKE '%RALPH%'
ORDER BY SURNAME
```

In MSSMS when I run the query I get the following results:

[image]

However, when I run the sql using DbSet.SqlQuery() I get the following results:

[image]

Note how the department object is null in the first item, yet has been populated in the second item.

I know I haven't provided much information, I'm hoping there's just a simple answer for this.

By the way..

```
DataContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

LazyLoadingEnabled is set to false as you can see, I know changing this to true would fix the issue. I'd just rather not go enabling it for whichever call I fancy needs it.

Thanks guys

Comment: Why are you using `SqlQuery` and not a proper EF query?

Comment: I have a list of People that I perform a filter on.. using the criteria provided by the user I generate an sql statement. There are many potential variations of the search so an sql statement seemed like the way to go.

Comment: It's almost certainly not the way to go, otherwise there's no point in using EF.

Comment: Okay, well I appreciate your comment and I shall see about changing that! Do you care to provide a reason of why the following is happening anyway?

Comment: Had you previously loaded the Department into that DbContext instance?  If so EF will recognize that it already has the Department with DepartmentId=2, and will set the navigation property to that instance.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thankyou! I've just ran a quick test and earlier in the query that particular Department is infact accessed. Feel free to add the comment as an answer and I'll accept it :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have previously loaded the Department into that DbContext instance, EF Change Tracking will recognize that it already has the Department with DepartmentId=2, and will set the navigation property to that instance.